# Is a Slack channel id unique across teams?

Tags: slack-api, slack

Is a Slack [channel](https://api.slack.com/types/channel)/[group](https://api.slack.com/types/group)/[im](https://api.slack.com/types/im)/[mpim](https://api.slack.com/types/mpim) id unique across different teams? In other words, can two teams have channels with the same id?

I read the docs, searched on Google and here on SO, but could not get confirmation if channel IDs are unique or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Slack plans to clarify this in documentation soon. While in the present day you'd probably get by just fine assuming IDs are unique across different teams, we strongly recommend scoping all of your storage and retrieval by team ID.

Essentially, we recommend considering IDs as only unique within teams, regardless of if experientially they are globally unique.

This is the best way to protect yourself for the future.

Comment: Will user slack references remain unique across different teams? (I assume yes, but in case!)

Comment: @ThibautBarrère no, user IDs are team-specific as well. It is not currently possible to reliably track a user across teams.

Answer (score 1):

## Update (May 2021)

While certain Slack API methods (e.g. [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info) and [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info)) operate on a channel ID and do not require a team ID, it is possible that they infer the team ID based on the provided Slack token ("user", "bot", "classic bot") which is scoped to the Slack team. (Thanks [@zizzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4971311/zizzo) for pointing this out in the comments below.)

## Original Post (March 2020)

Interestingly, the Slack API methods [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info) and [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) only accept a channel ID or user ID, without a team ID. This suggests that scoping by team IDs may not actually be necessary.

Since the `conversations.info` method did not exist<sup>[1]</sup> (not publicly, anyway) at the time of Taylor Singletary's original answer, the guidance regarding ID scoping may have changed since then.

#### Footnotes

1. Deprecating early methods in favor of the Conversations API. https://api.slack.com/changelog/2020-01-deprecating-antecedents-to-the-conversations-api

   > We released the [Conversations API](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api) in September 2017 as a one-size-fits-all replacement for a variety of APIs used to read and write information about channels, private channels, direct messages, and multi-party direct messages.

Comment: those API methods accept only channel/user ID because they are already scoped thanks to the access token you have to send together with the request (the access token is bound to a Slack Team)

Comment: Good point @zizzo. `conversations.info` and `users.info` require a "user"/"bot"/"classic bot" token. According to https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types, are only "app" tokens _not_ Slack Team-scoped?