# Slack user id and access token unique across teams or users

Tags: slack-api

Are user id's in Slack unique across teams or users? For instance, if User A installs an app for Team A and Team B is that users's id and access token the same between both teams?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a Slack channel id unique across teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566439/is-a-slack-channel-id-unique-across-teams)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slack user IDs are only unique to the team containing them -- you might encounter re-used IDs when working with other teams, and Slack encourages you to keep this in mind when storing IDs -- you'll want to partition them by team ID.

Answer (score 6):

As of writing, **User IDs are now globally unique.**

[More info here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.identity#markdown)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation id is unique only within a team.

https://api.slack.com/types/user

> id, String - Identifier for this workspace user. It is unique to the workspace containing the user. Use this field together with team_id as a unique key when storing related data or when specifying the user in API requests. We recommend considering the format of the string to be an opaque value, and not to rely on a particular structure.