# Slack Channel/User Ids and chat.postMessage

Tags: slack, slack-api

The Slack API documentation specifies that `user_id` is not globally unique [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566439/is-a-slack-channel-id-unique-across-teams/35634747#35634747) seems to state that `channel_id` isn't necessarily unique either.

Now my question is about the `chat.postMessage` API endpoint. It takes a `channel_id` or `user_id` for the channel, but has no way to specify a team. So can we as the caller still assume that those are effectively unique? The post [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566439/is-a-slack-channel-id-unique-across-teams/35634747#35634747) is over a year old, and I haven't found any updates, so I don't know if that assumption still holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the team/workspace is implicit in the `token` you're using to execute the `chat.postMessage` request. All specified channel IDs and user IDs will be considered within the domain of that implicit team.

Comment: Ah. Since the token showed up in the app configuration page I assumed it was specific to the app, not the team. My bad.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a "convenience feature" that they display there -- to help you more quickly get started against your own team.